でもしそう? What grammar is this?

舌打ちでもしそうな勢いで憎々しげに呟き彼は進める。

How is でもしそう used here? I understand he advances with vigor and murmuring hateful, but?

The し in しそう is the stem form of the auxiliar verb する, そう after stem means "looking/sounding as if ___." (please read this answer for more details about this そう).
舌打ち is "clicking one's tongue".
This でも means "(...) or something" (4th meaning in Jisho).
